# How do I test method that reads data from file

Tags: qt, qttest

I have a class with following constructor: `MyClass(QFile& file);`. I want to unit-test it with [Qt Test framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html). How do I specify content of the file from a unit-test (without actually creating a real file)?

Comment: You could use a `QTemporaryFile`. [More info](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporaryfile.html).

Comment: @Tarod Thank you, it worked for me. Although I still think that some kind of proxy would be better, so I don't have to create event temp file.

Comment: Bundle the test data in a Qt resource and read it from there. Or implement your logic to operate on QIODevice. I don’t see what’s wrong with supplying the test data via resource-bundles files though.